# jython how to retrieve the operating system name

Tags: jython

How to determin the underlying OS, jython is running on. Not 'java', but 'nt' or 'posix'.

- platform.platform
- os.name
- and sys.platform
  only return 'java'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For jython I use `java.lang.System.getProperty("os.name")`:

```
import sys

def get_os_version():
    ver = sys.platform.lower()
    if ver.startswith('java'):
        import java.lang
        ver = java.lang.System.getProperty("os.name").lower()
    return ver

print(get_os_version())
```